# Object (promise.all) to useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to set an object to useSate.
The object is the **dataMap** which should be passed to the **setResults**
Any help would be appreciated ?

```
export default function Home() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const fetchResults = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      'someurl'
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    const dataMap = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [curr.id]: curr
      };
    }, {});

    const requests = Object.keys(dataMap).map(async (productId) => {
      const request = await fetch(
        `someUrl/${productId}`
      );
      const response = await request.json();
      return response;
    });
    const responseAll = await Promise.all(requests);
    responseAll.forEach(
      ({ id, color }) => (dataMap[id] = { ...dataMap[id], color })
    );  
    //console.log(dataMap);
    setResults(dataMap)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const requests = Object.keys(dataMap).map(async (productId) => {
      const request = await fetch(
        `someUrl/${productId}`
      );
      const response = await request.json();
      return response;
    });
```

**This piece of code will trigger all the api's till the end of `Object.keys(dataMap)`**

To update the state with the values.

**You need to update the state just after await like this**:

```js
 const requests = Object.keys(dataMap).map(async (productId) => {
      const request = await fetch(
        `someUrl/${productId}`
      );
      const response = await request.json();
      setResults(prev=>[...prev,response])
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. It double the results ... ?

Comment: I am getting all the data double is the state

Comment: ```js
const responseAll = await Promise.all(requests);
    responseAll.forEach(
      ({ id, color }) => (dataMap[id] = { ...dataMap[id], color })
    );  ``` You need to remove this code.

` const responseAll = await Promise.all(requests); `
There is nothing to wait here all requests were started.

Comment: property 'id' of 'param' as it is undefined?

Comment: i am still getting double after removing ???!!?!?